# Push notification using Azure

Tags: php, android, iphone, azure, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement push notification service of Azure.

I need the service to be functional on all **Android**,**iPhone** and  **Windows phone 8**.

Earlier I have done using GCM-Android and APNS-iPhone.

I need to implement the same for all but using azure only, and my local server is in php. When I am implementing the code I want to separate devices on my php server on some random basis and categorized them in groups. Then the notification should be sent to some groups and its users(Devices).

How can I handle the situation. I have tried the implementation of **Notification hub** but for implementing the group it fails.
I have tried to implement using **mobile services**, but that too ends nowhere. 
I have also tried to set tag over my php server but no positive output.

I am new to this, it would be great if I can get some tutorial or Sample.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you tried and how the implementation failed?